# jQuery json don't output the right value

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to output the **"title", "url", "imageUrl"** but it only shows **"undefined" or "[object Object]"**, and I have to solve this

My code should output like this:

```
<p>The Word</p>
<p>Art</p>
<p>Attaining</p>
```

Here is my JSON code:

```
{
    "ebookList":{
        "ebook":[
            {
                "title":"The Word",
                "url":"/products/",
                "imageUrl":"/products/",
                "_id":"1"
            },
            {
                "title":"Art",
                "url":"/products/",
                "imageUrl":"/products/",
                "_id":"2"
            },
            {
                "title":"Attaining",
                "url":"/products/",
                "imageUrl":"/products/",
                "_id":"3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and my javascript:

```
function loadBooks() {
    $.getJSON('products/books.json', function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, res) {
            alert(res.title);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `$.each(result.ebookList.ebook, function (i, res) {
            alert(res.title);
        });` or `$.each(result['ebookList']['ebook'], function (i, res) {
            alert(res.title);
        });`

Comment: So, it'll be the same as the other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do `each` on result which is the whole table. So your `res` variable will contain every iteration of `ebook` and here you have only one. The `ebook` array does not contain any `title` attribute (which explains the `undefined` you get), it only contains objects (3 arrays in that example, that explain the output you have when doing `alert(res)`), that contain `title` attributes among others.

So to do what you want, you have to do `$.each(result.ebookList.ebook, function (i, res)` that will loop through the objects inside the `ebook` object.

Answer (score 1):

To alert the titles use this loop.

```
for(i=0; i<result.ebookList.ebook.length; i++){
  alert(result.ebookList.ebook[i].title);
}
```

Comment: function loadEbooks() {
    $.getJSON('products/ebooks.json', function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, res) {
            for (var j in i) {
                $('#ebooks .contents').append('<p>' + res['ebook'][j].title + '</p>');
            }
        });
    });
} also works but it only show 9 results when I've added my json "ebook"

Comment: Withou $.each, my loop does the same in pure JavaScript